# Add a cookie in a Play Framework 2.x filter?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to add a cookie in the Play Framework's doFilter method in the Global class?

I've tried:

```
override def doFilter(action: EssentialAction): EssentialAction = EssentialAction { request =>
  if (request.queryString.contains("q")) {
    action.apply(request).map(_.withCookies(
      Cookie("q", request.queryString.get("q").get(0), 3600)
    ))
  }
}
```

but the cookie doesn't get sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Playframework 2.2 and use a similar thing:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object ResponseFilter extends Filter {
  def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])(rh: RequestHeader) = {
    next(rh).map(_.withHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*").as("application/json; charset=utf-8"))
  }
}
```

And my `Global` object looks like this:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import service.ResponseFilter

object Global extends WithFilters(ResponseFilter) with GlobalSettings
```

This works fine for me. So I suppose you could replace the `_.withHeaders(...)` part with the `_.withCookies(...)` part and that would work for you as well.

Please note that things are a bit different in earlier versions of playframework